# Use Blade Array/Objects like Twig

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, twig, laravel-blade

Is there a way to treat objects and arrays the same in Blade (like twig).

So that no matter what, you access the object and array with dot-notation, or even "->" notation would be fine.  I would like to not have to differentiate between an object and an array.  Twig allows this, but blade does not.  I want to know if there is an extension/change I can make to blade to allow the same feature as twig.

For example an object containing an array:

DATA:

```
$object = [ (object)
    part_1 => [
        part_2 => [ (array)
            array_1 => "test"
        ]
    ]
]
```

BLADE:

```
$object->part_1->part_2['array_1']
//returns "test"

$object->part_1->part_2->array_1
//fails "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

TWIG:

```
object.part_1.part_2.array_1
//returns "test"
```

Also explained as so:
Twig makes it easy to access variables using the dot notation.
This can be used on either a object or array.
In Blade, it’s the same as plain PHP.

BLADE ----------------- TWIG
$user->name -------> user.name
$user['name'] -------> user.name

Comment: treating both the same actually makes it more confusing, or no?

Answer (score 0):

To use "->" -notation, the variable has to be of PHP's type StdClass. An array (or associative array) is not. Although, you can easily cast it :)

```
$stdObj = (object) ["prop" => "value"];
```

As @Bryce said,

> this will not work for multidimensional array

. However, you can find your answer of converting it here https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Comment: casting does not work for multi-dimensional data.  It only casts the upper most parent, and leaves the children still as arrays.